# I am trying to create a table in MySQL with 3 foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, heidisql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `formationnote` (
    `IdEvaluation` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `IdF` int(11),  
    `IdC` int(11),
    `user_id` int(11),
    `note` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`IdEvaluation`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdF`) REFERENCES formations(`IdF`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdC`) REFERENCES competences(`IdC`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES users(`user_id``)
)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: ya samir mahia mochkila hone ^^  is it : user_id``